# How can I return children prop in react only after my useEffect code runs. (synchronous behaviour)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, jwt

I am trying to create axios interceptor wrapper for my axios request to handle JWT tokens.

What I want is to run the interceptor code first inside the useEffect block and then return children so that the children returns with new access token and eventually a successfull api call. but instead what I am getting is, it is returning with the old jwt token and the api call happens with an expired token resulting to an error.

```
const AxiosPrivateInterceptor: FC<IProps> = ({ children }) => {
    const { user } = useAppSelector(selectAuthUser);
    const refresh = useRefreshToken();

    useEffect(() => {
        const requestIntercept = axiosPrivate.interceptors.request.use(
            (config: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
                config.headers = config.headers ?? {};
                if (!config?.headers["Authorization"]) {
                    config.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${user?.accessToken}`;
                }
                return config;
            },
            (error) => Promise.reject(error)
        );

        const responseIntercept = axiosPrivate.interceptors.response.use(
            (response) => response,
            async (error) => {
                const prevRequest = error?.config;
                if (error?.response.status === 403 && !prevRequest?.sent) {
                    prevRequest.send = true;
                    const newToken = await refresh();
                    const accessToken = newToken.accessToken;
                    prevRequest.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
                    return axiosPrivate(prevRequest);
                }
                return Promise.reject(error);
            }
        );

        return () => {
            axiosPrivate.interceptors.request.eject(requestIntercept);
            axiosPrivate.interceptors.response.eject(responseIntercept);
        };
    }, [user, refresh]);

    return children;
};


I also tried to add a state like this :

const AxiosPrivateInterceptor: FC<IProps> = ({ children }) => {
    const { user } = useAppSelector(selectAuthUser);
    const refresh = useRefreshToken();
    const [isSet, setIsSet] = useState<boolean>(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const requestIntercept = axiosPrivate.interceptors.request.use(
            (config: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
                config.headers = config.headers ?? {};
                if (!config?.headers["Authorization"]) {
                    config.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${user?.accessToken}`;
                }
                return config;
            },
            (error) => Promise.reject(error)
        );

        const responseIntercept = axiosPrivate.interceptors.response.use(
            (response) => response,
            async (error) => {
                const prevRequest = error?.config;
                if (error?.response.status === 403 && !prevRequest?.sent) {
                    prevRequest.send = true;
                    const newToken = await refresh();
                    const accessToken = newToken.accessToken;
                    prevRequest.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
                    return axiosPrivate(prevRequest);
                }
                return Promise.reject(error);
            }
        );
setIsSet(true)

        return () => {
            axiosPrivate.interceptors.request.eject(requestIntercept);
            axiosPrivate.interceptors.response.eject(responseIntercept);
        };
    }, [user, refresh]);

    return isSet && children;
};

But typescript won't allow me to do that.
```

How this issue can be solved?

Answer (score 1):

Although this did not fix my main issue, but I figured out that it's quite easy to bypass this typescript error:

```
return <>{isSet && children}</>
```

Comment: Yup, wrapping it in a fragment means that it will always return a `JSX.Element`, which is good because a component must return `JSX.Element | null`.  If you are returning `isSet` which is `false` then you are breaking that rule.

Comment: It's also possible to do `return isSet ? children : null;` but only if you refine the type of the `children` prop (from `ReactNode` to `JSX.Element | null`), so that's more roundabout/difficult.